# How to lock screen or hibernate when lid closed

Tags: hibernate, lock, lid

when I close the lid I want to have the screen locked or PC hibernate (choice with menu like win 10). 
How to do it (16.04)?
Thanks
Serros

Comment: Huh? You want a dialog window asking you whether to only lock the screen or hibernate when you close the notebook lid? How would you answer anything with the lid closed then?

Comment: Actually, I want to have the choice to lock the screen or hibernate if i close the lid.
At least to lock, because now it only suspends...

Comment: What is your settings in __Security & Privacy__?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go in the system settings, in "Brightness & Lock"

[image]

Check "Require my password when waking from suspend".